# Javascript Hide an If statement with another If Statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I want to hide an If statement if the user is on a mobile device. I tried with another if statement:

```
if(version.major === 0) {
                document.write('Du benutzt aktuell keinen Flash Player! ');
                flashPlayerVersion.style.display = 'none';
            }
```

and with this If statement I tried to hide the other one if the user is a mobile user.

```
 var mobile = (/iphone|playbook|windows phone|mobile|silk browser|android.webkit.WebView|web app runtime|kindle|kindle fire|blackberry|ipod|ipad|android|blackberry|mini|windows\sce|palm/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));
    if (mobile) {
        FlashNotification.style.display = 'none';

    }
```

Now i want to hide the flashPlayerVersion ...

Hope you could understand my question  ^^

Comment: I recommend feature detection rather than browser detection. See https://modernizr.com/. It's well supported.

Comment: `if(version.major === 0 || mobile) {...}`?!

Answer (score 1):

What about this (if i understand your question correctly):

```
var mobile = (/iphone|playbook|windows phone|mobile|silk browser|android.webkit.WebView|web app runtime|kindle|kindle fire|blackberry|ipod|ipad|android|blackberry|mini|windows\sce|palm/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));
if (mobile) {
    FlashNotification.style.display = 'none';

}else{
    if(version.major === 0) {
            document.write('Du benutzt aktuell keinen Flash Player! ');
            flashPlayerVersion.style.display = 'none';
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put one if inside the other:

```
if (version.major === 0) {
    var mobile = (/iphone|playbook|windows phone|mobile|silk browser|android.webkit.WebView|web app runtime|kindle|kindle fire|blackberry|ipod|ipad|android|blackberry|mini|windows\sce|palm/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));

    if (mobile) {
        FlashNotification.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        document.write('Du benutzt aktuell keinen Flash Player! ');
        flashPlayerVersion.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not for browser detection, it becomes very tricky when you're factoring in mobile devices. Detect if flash is installed on users device. Not entirely sure I've understood your question...

```
var _flash_installed = ((typeof navigator.plugins != "undefined" && typeof navigator.plugins["Shockwave Flash"] == "object") || (window.ActiveXObject && (new ActiveXObject("ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash")) != false));
```